# Error SQL query php

Tags: php, sql

I get this error when i try to update my database with som moviegenres.

```
UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET

Error in executing query: 42000 Array
(
[0] => 42000
[1] => 1064
[2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Movies are saved but not with genres. Anybody who could see what's wrong here? I know it's in the UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET (marked in bold) but I can't see what's wrong...

```
$output = null;
if($save) {
 // First save information on movie
 $sql = '
UPDATE RM_Movie SET
  title = ?,
  year = ?,
  image = ?,
  pris = ?,
  director = ?,
  length = ?,
  plot = ?,
  imdb = ?,
  trailer = ?,
  filter = ?
WHERE 
  id = ?
';
 $params = array($title, $year, $image, $pris, $director, $length, $plot, $imdb, $trailer, $filter, $id);
$db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $params);

// Then save information on genre
foreach($genre as $val) {
   **$db->ExecuteQuery('UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET', array($val));**
}
$output = 'Informationen sparades';
}
```

This code will only replace all movies with the updated/inserted movie. I will use my code for both update and insert.

```
// Get all genres and select those that should be selected
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM RM_MovieGenre';
$genres = $db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql);

$sql = 'SELECT idRM_MovieGenre AS id FROM RM_Movie2Genre WHERE idRM_Movie = ?';
$myGenres = $db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql, array($id), 0, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$selectOptionGenres = "<select multiple name='genre[]'>";
 foreach($genres as $key => $val) {
$selected = in_array($val->id, $myGenres) ? ' selected' : null;
$selectOptionGenres .= "<option value='{$val->id}'{$selected}>{$val->name}</option>";
}
$selectOptionGenres .= '</select>';


// Check if form was submitted
$output = null;
if($save) {
// First save information on movie
$sql = '
UPDATE RM_Movie SET
  title = ?,
  year = ?,
  image = ?,
  pris = ?,
  director = ?,
  length = ?,
  plot = ?,
  imdb = ?,
  trailer = ?,
  filter = ?
 ';
 $params = array($title, $year, $image, $pris, $director, $length, $plot, $imdb, $trailer, $filter);
 $db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $params);

 // Then save information on genre
 $query="INSERT INTO RM_Movie2Genre(idRM_Movie,idRM_MovieGenre) values($id,?)";

foreach($genre as $val) {
   $val_array=array($val);
   $db->ExecuteQuery($query, $val_array);
}
 $output = 'Informationen sparades';
}

// Select information on the movie 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM RM_Movie WHERE id = ?';
$params = array($id);
$res = $db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql, $params);

if(isset($res[0])) {
$movie = $res[0];
}
else {
 die('Failed: There is no movie with that id');
}
```

Comment: Print out the SQL query before running it. You'll figure out what's wrong then. If you use prepared statements (which it looks like) you can fake it by using `echo vsprintf(str_replace('?', '\'%s\'', $query), $params);`

Comment: you are missing field name after the `SET': UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET FIELD_NAME=...

Comment: @Ormoz I tried to update it with
    $db->ExecuteQuery('UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET genre = (array($val)) WHERE id =?');
but got this problem instead
    Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in ...

Comment: @h2ooooooo How do I do that?

Comment: @MiaRaunegger Change your `ExecuteQuery` method.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to change the value of the row with :

```
 $id=$params[10];
```

I think you have multiple genres for a single id and you store it in the RM_Movie2Genre table. if it is the case you should use `INSERT` query. But first, you should delete old values:

```
   $query="DELETE FROM RM_Movie2Genre where id=?";

   $val_array=array($id);
   $db->ExecuteQuery($query, $val_array);
```

Now, for inserting, If the $id is numeric use this query:

```
 $query="INSERT INTO RM_Movie2Genre(id,genre) values($id,?)";
```

otherwise if it is of string type, you should wrap $id with single quotes:

```
 $query="INSERT INTO RM_Movie2Genre(id,genre) values('$id',?)";
```

and finally:

```
foreach($genre as $val) {
   $val_array=array($val);
   $db->ExecuteQuery($query, $val_array);
}
```

I do not think `UPDATE` makes any sense because with the update query you are updating a single row several times which is useless. anyway if you still think you should `update` query then change the `$query` with this one:

```
 $query="UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET genre = ? WHERE id =$id";
```

and if it is of string type:

```
 $query="UPDATE RM_Movie2Genre SET genre = ?  WHERE id ='$id'";
```

Comment: I'm using the same file for both update movies and insert new movies, so it's not a good idea to delete the information first.
I tried with your suggestions of both INSERT and UPDATE but the result is that all other movies disapear and replaces with the updated/inserted movie.
Id is numeric.
I have updated myc code above with more.

Comment: You have missed `where clause` in the query: `$sql = '
UPDATE RM_Movie SET
  title = ?,
  year = ?,
  image = ?,
  pris = ?,
  director = ?,
  length = ?,
  plot = ?,
  imdb = ?,
  trailer = ?,
  filter = ?
 ';`  . It obviously updates all records!

Comment: You cant update and insert movies in one single file and at the same time using delete query to update genres. In fact, this way is the simplest way to update genres. using update query for updating genre requires far more complicated coding. you can not update genres with just one update query.So, better stick to deleting and updating genres. (NOTICE, you are deleteing genres, not the movie itself)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked just fine for both create and edit. Thanks all for getting me there! :-)

```
// Get all genres and select those that should be selected
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM RM_MovieGenre';
$genres = $db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql);

$sql = 'SELECT idRM_MovieGenre AS id FROM RM_Movie2Genre WHERE idRM_Movie = ?';
$myGenres = $db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql, array($id), 0, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$selectOptionGenres = "<select multiple name='genre[]'>";
foreach($genres as $key => $val) {
  $selected = in_array($val->id, $myGenres) ? ' selected' : null;
  $selectOptionGenres .= "<option value='{$val->id}'{$selected}>{$val->name}</option>";
}
$selectOptionGenres .= '</select>';


// Check if form was submitted
$output = null;
if($save) {
  // First save information on movie
  $sql = '
    UPDATE RM_Movie SET
      title = ?,
      year = ?,
      image = ?,
      pris = ?,
      director = ?,
      length = ?,
      plot = ?,
      imdb = ?,
      trailer = ?,
      filter = ?
    WHERE 
      id = ?
  ';
  $params = array($title, $year, $image, $pris, $director, $length, $plot, $imdb, $trailer, $filter, $id);
  $db->ExecuteQuery($sql, $params);

    // Then save information on genre
    $query="INSERT INTO RM_Movie2Genre(idRM_Movie,idRM_MovieGenre) values($id,?)";

    foreach($genre as $val) {
       $val_array=array($val);
       $db->ExecuteQuery($query, $val_array);
    }
  $output = 'Informationen sparades';
}

// Select information on the movie 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM RM_Movie WHERE id = ?';
$params = array($id);
$res = $db->ExecuteSelectQueryAndFetchAll($sql, $params);

if(isset($res[0])) {
  $movie = $res[0];
}
else {
  die('Failed: There is no movie with that id');
}
```